# Displaying top 5 active processes in unix

Tags: unix

I am newbie and I would like to know how to display the top 5 active processes and their CPU usage.

Below are some of the unix commands that I've tried but did not work:

1. top
2. top -n 5 - Displayed all the processes I have instead of 5

Comment: top -n 5 works for me.  What version of top are you running?

Comment: This is silly but how do I check the version of top that I'm running?

Comment: `top -v`.  Also what operating system are you using?  `uname -a`

Comment: top -n command works ok on solaris.  Linux top is different. :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what the `n` option stands for. This option is actually the maximum number of times that `top` will look for "updates". This will output you the 5 processes at the top of the list :

```
top -n 1 -b|head -n12|tail -n 5
```

`top -n 1 -b` makes the program static so that it outputs the data instead of starting an interactive shell.

`head -n 12` filters out the 12 first lines (I counted it, 7 lines of headers plus your 5 processes).

Finally, `tail -n 5` filters out the 5 last lines and gives you only the processes. Replace it with `tail -n 6` if you want to include the column names.